# How do I get rid of the key to the right on a chart made via Google Visualizations API?

Tags: google-visualization

I made this chart of China's GDP growth with Google visualizations.

http://bit.ly/yGmL29

How do I get rid of the key to the right (as it is redundant in this case)? I had been searching around the documentation, but I couldn't find a concrete means of doing so. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this using the `legend.position` option. Updating your options to look like this will remove it:

```
    var options = {
      width: 900, height: 440,
      title: 'GDP Per Capita ($) of the People\'s Republic of China vs Year',
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      }
    };
```

It's listed in the docs, see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html#Configuration_Options) for more linechart configs. Hope that helps.